# How to get multiple variables from a While Statement?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, mysqli

I need to fetch between 1 and 3 tags from a Mysql Database. Then I'd like to assign each tag to a variable. Does anybody know how I can do this? Here's the code

```
$findTag1= "SELECT tagid FROM entitytag WHERE audioid = '$audioid'";    
$findTag1Result = $link->query($findTag1);

if ($findTag1Result->num_rows >= 0) {     
while($row = $findTag1Result->fetch_assoc()) {
          //Assign each tag to a variable
      } 
}
```

Comment: Store them in an array instead. Declare `$tags = [];` before your loop, and inside just do `$tags[] = $row['tagid'];`. Then you have them all inside your `$tags` variable. Don't get any ideas about using "variable variables", they will come back and bite you in your butt. Use arrays.

Comment: Assuming that the number of tags fetched from DB is unknown it's bad practice to create named variables from them. Althought you can do it as @my_name_is_njuno showed with `extract()` function it's **definitely better** to keep them in an associative array as he showed in the first part of his answer, and then iterate this array to work with its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mysqli then you can do this using `fetch_all()` and `array_column()`. This will produce an array where each element is the tag coming from your database. It would be much easier if you used PDO, and I strongly recommend to make the switch if it is not too late.

To do this using mysqli you can do so:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    'SELECT tagid 
    FROM entitytag 
    WHERE audioid = ? 
    ORDER BY tagid 
    LIMIT 3'
);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $audioid);
$stmt->execute();
$tags = array_column($stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(), 0);

// Either loop on all 3 tags assigning each to a variable
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag;
}
// or access each one via its index. 0 = first tag, 1 = second tag, 2 = third tag
echo $tags[1] ?? 'No tag!';
```

You can access the elements in the array variable either by looping on the array of by using numerical indices. If you decide to use indices make sure that you provide a default value in case you have less than 3 tags in the array. Use `?? 'default'` syntax.

Answer (score -2):

This would work, but not sure how you will manage to predict the number of variables you will have, I still prefer to stick with arrays without extracting their content to variables.

```
/// assign inside while loop
$tags[] = $row->tag;

// use variables outside the loop
list($tag1, $tag2, $tag3) = $tags;
```

Comment: Are yu sure there will be always 3 tags?

Answer (score -2):

put the results in an associative array

```
$array = []; 
$i = 1;
while($row=findTag1Result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array['tag' . $i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

then use extract to get your variables.

```
extract($array);
```

Comment: That sounds logical, however i wouldn't extract it to variables, instead work with `$array` ie. iterating it in `foreach` loop.